# Facerecognition in Android studio using all the images from gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, face-recognition

I am trying to make an Android application (in Android Studio) using my images from gallery for face recognition. Here is my source code (using what I found from an open course web page) which is collecting my images, but I just want those images to show which contain at least a face. I know that somehow I need to use the `FaceDetection`, but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns,
        null,
        null,
        orderBy
    );
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            id,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
            null
        );
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    Bitmap bitmap_column;
    bitmap_column = new Bitmap(thumbnails);

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmap = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    imageWidth = thumbnails.getWidth();
    imageHeight = thumbnails.getHeight();

    myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
    myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);
    numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(thumbnails, myFace);

    imagecursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please select at least one image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`ImageAdapter` class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.galleryitem,
                null
            );
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

`ViewHolder` class:

```
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean hasFace(Bitmap inBmp){
    Bitmap bmp = inBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    FaceDetector fd = new FaceDetector(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 1);
    Face faces[] = new Face[1];
    int numFaces = fd.findFaces(bmp, faces);
    bmp.recycle();
    return numFaces > 0;
}
```

This will tell you if a bitmap has a face or not.  Walk your cursor, and add only the images that return true to the array you pass to your adapter.  I would highly suggest doing that on an AsyncTask due to the amount of time it will take to run.  I'd also suggest setting it up so it either populates the adapter periodically (as this will take a while) or at least shows a processing UI of some sort so the user knows it will take a while.

Comment: OK, it seems good, but how can I build this method in the loop where I have a bitmap[], because I need to use this method for every singe picture

Comment: Loop calling it for each bitmap in the array.  There's no more efficient API used for multiple images, you're stuck with this.  The only thing you can really improve is removing the copy if the bitmap is in the 565 format already.